# Gratis Android file manager for Windows PC

Tags: windows, gratis, android, file-management

I am looking for a gratis PC program which will let me connect to my Android phone. USB connection is fine, WiFi is a bonus.

It should be aware of all the common file locations and allow me to transfer music, ring tones, photos (hopefully ebooks), etc back & forth.

I would also like to be able to have full access to the file system. So, both easy & expert mode.

Backup & restore would be nice.

A prime concern is the lack of obtrusive advertising. I realize they have to make money somehow, so can live with an app store, which I can ignore.

I used to use MoboRobo, but it doesn't seem to work with my new 'phone (plus, when I go to their "[download for Android](http://download.moborobo.com/download/App/mobomarket/OfficialHomePage/MoboMarket.apk)" page, Google has a large, fierce, security warning)

Comment: I use open source [**Droid Explorer**](https://de.codeplex.com/), it must match almost all your requirements. Thanks.

Comment: It looks good (+1) - but it is only a file manager, it doen't "know" where my photos, videios, music, ebooks are